# Creating a technical excel data sheet to display efficient data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I am creating a table in excel that holds milestone achievement data with their respective amount. This table has multiple milestones that have only one amount, meaning that a set of milestone documents having different name will contain same achievements and that particular documents amount will be a singular value (One total amount).

Example table for better understanding:
[image: Example table for better understanding]

My question is, how can I create an efficient table that contains all these data without the need to merge the amount rows?

P.S. The next step for me will be creating pie charts and visual data for presentation purposes.

Comment: What do you want the result table to look like?

Comment: @ExcelNoob It would be useful to provide you input data and desired output table. For me it is still puzzlin how you want to have this aggregated with the amounts, aprticularly for the same sheets but different documents.

Comment: I will only have one sheet that has one excel table. This table will record all the milestone  achievement documents name (in first column). These milestone documents are usually bundled up to calculate a total price (which is my amount column). When entering data I do not want to copy and paste the amount eg. 250 (from picture) to the below cells. So, how can I redesign this table so that the amount 250 is shown for all the bundled documents and when I do =SUM of the amounts it gets summed once.

Comment: @karl for more clarification, as per the picture provided you can see that 250 is written for Doc B but the amount of the three docs below is blank because that 250 is for all Doc B, C, D, E. I do not want to use merge to show that 250 belongs to all for documents.

Comment: @harrymc It can look similar to the example but the only issue with this example template is that I will have to merge the amount column of the four rows with (S.N.# 2) and that will cause hinderance in sorting or creating visual data. How can I change the look of the table in such a way that I mitigate this issue?

Comment: @ExcelNoob Why can you simple use the S.N.# value as unique identified? Based on this you could get the aggregate amounts (if it is more than one row), and based on this you can make your charts?

Comment: @karl I thought so at first as well but when I complete this table and make a visual chart (pie chart or some other chart for presentation) out of this it will cause issues as the data I will need to showcase is the milestone document names and the amount each carry. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @ExcelNoob I don't understand what you mean with "and the amount each carry". Can you edit your question and provide a more comprehensible example, including the cases where they have multiple amounts etc.?

Comment: @karl In the picture the cells below 250 are empty. Because 250 value is for documents (B, C, D, E). I don't want to merge the cells below and including 250 to make it look like one cell. How would you create a table such that you do not have to merge or duplicate 250 down below>